# How do I update entities or objects in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I am using a component that I can code in HTML. For example with the [text geometry component](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-text-component), I created text:

```
<a-entity text="text: 0"></a-entity>
```

How do I update the `text` component's `text` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Entity.setAttribute](https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/entity.html#setattribute-attr-value-componentattrvalue)

Just like updating normal DOM elements, we can use `setAttribute`.

```
el.setAttribute('visible', false);
```

If a component has multiple properties, we have three arguments. Component name, property name, value:

```
el.setAttribute('material', 'color', 'black');
el.setAttribute('text', 'text', '1');
```

Where to put this code? Within a component would be good:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('update-text-every-second', {
  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;
    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
      el.setAttribute('text', 'text', i.toString());
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

And use:

```
<a-entity text="text: 0" update-text-every-second></a-entity>
```